# How does one change the editor that brew uses?

Tags: homebrew

When I run `brew edit _some_formula_`, it opens up vim. I tried changing the `$EDITOR` variable of my terminal to `emacs`, but it still uses vim. How can I change the editor that brew uses when calling `brew edit`?

Answer (score 5):

Homebrew searches for your editor in the environment variables `HOMEBREW_EDITOR`, `VISUAL`, and `EDITOR` in that order. If none of these are defined, Homebrew will try to use, in order: TextMate, TextWrangler, or the system install of Vim.

Built-in Homebrew commands are defined in `/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd`, assuming a default install location. Examining `edit.rb` in that folder we see that the editor is located [with the function `which_editor`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/9a26171eb6/Library/Homebrew/cmd/edit.rb#L15). Grepping for `which_editor` brings us to [`utils.rb`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/b509defa1d/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb#L180):

```
def which_editor
  editor = ENV.values_at('HOMEBREW_EDITOR', 'VISUAL', 'EDITOR').compact.first
  # If an editor wasn't set, try to pick a sane default
  return editor unless editor.nil?

  # Find Textmate
  return 'mate' if which "mate"
  # Find BBEdit / TextWrangler
  return 'edit' if which "edit"
  # Default to vim
  return '/usr/bin/vim'
end
```